# Unity - detect last frame of video in MovieTexture

Tags: video, unity-game-engine

Right now I have the following simple script to play a Movietexture on a Plane. I want to be able to detect the last frame so I can trigger a countdown script in another Text component. What changes do I need to make?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (AudioSource))]
public class VideController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Screen.SetResolution (768, 1024, false, 60);
        MovieTexture movie =    renderer.material.mainTexture as MovieTexture;
        audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
        audio.Play ();
        movie.Play ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: A quick google yielded these solutions: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/on-movie-end-switch-levels.47929/
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/202303/on-movie-end.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check in update that if movie is ended or not and set a bool to don't start the count down every frame

```
 void Update () {
  if(!movie.isPlaying && inCountDown=false)
    {
      //start the count down
     inCountDown=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Disappointed the the video options are SO limited in Unity. You should be able to get the frame# of the video, etc

Comment: just use a coroutine ... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/202303/on-movie-end.html#answer-1000687